# Read datetime from text file in matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have the following text file with datetime in the first column. The file is:

```
23/7/1998 20:00;"   1.8 "
23/7/1998 21:00;"   1.7 "
23/7/1998 22:00;"   2.2 "
23/7/1998 23:00;"   2.5 "
24/7/1998 0:00;"    2.2 "
24/7/1998 1:00;"    2.3 "
24/7/1998 2:00;"    2.4 "
24/7/1998 3:00;"    1.8 "
24/7/1998 4:00;"    1.9 "
```

I would like to have the first column (datetime) as a string. I tried the function `datenum`, but with no success. Any help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @tostao [Please read this meta post about "What Have you Tried" comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/152134)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually read the strings:

```
fid = fopen('yourfile.txt','r');
aux_cell  = textscan(fid,'%s');
date_cell = aux_cell{1}(1:4:end);
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply read the file line-by-line and store the required data into a cell array as follows:

```
f_read = fopen('testcase.txt','r');    %The file 'testcase.txt' would contain the data of interest.
pat = '(?<datetime>[^;]*)(.*)';    %Regular expression to extract required field.
datetime = cell(0,1);
line = fgets(f_read);
while(line ~= -1)    %Till the end of file.
    line = regexp(line, pat, 'names');    %Extracts first column from input line.
    datetime = [datetime;line.datetime];    %Append result as next row.
    line = fgets(f_read);
end
```

For your input, the result would be:

```
>> datetime

datetime = 

    '23/7/1998 20:00'
    '23/7/1998 21:00'
    '23/7/1998 22:00'
    '23/7/1998 23:00'
    '24/7/1998 0:00'
    '24/7/1998 1:00'
    '24/7/1998 2:00'
    '24/7/1998 3:00'
    '24/7/1998 4:00'
```

Each individual record may be accessed as follows:

```
>> datetime{1}

ans =

23/7/1998 20:00
```